# Кэширование MySQL запросов

Tags: mysql

Ранее держал на VDS сложный скрипт, который выдаёт результаты своей работы (выборки из базы данных) за условный 1 час при первом обращении, а потом, видимо, результаты этих запросов как-то кэшировались, потому что при последующих обращениях и неизменных входных данных и данных в БД никакого часа ожидания не было, все практически мгновенно выдавалось. MySQL я не настраивал, какие конфиги по умолчанию на VDS были такие и использовались. ОС была Ubuntu 14.04, ЕМНИП.

А сейчас я перенёс этот скрипт на свою локальную машину (localhost) и оно так не работает -- каждый раз приходится ждать, пока все запросы пройдут, сгенирируются, в общем каждый час вот так ждать. Правда локальная машина Windows, и версии Apache/php/mysql соответствующие.

В сторону чего посмотреть, чтобы настроить/включить это кэширование запросов в MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас MySQL > 4.0 версии тогда может посмотреть в сторону [этой статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/41166/).